# Have weird issue with input in ascensor script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I have weird problem with the script ascensor.js

You can watch in my site :
[www.emantiss.com](http://www.emantiss.com)

Look down page into the contact form. I can't write anything.
I've tried to delete the script and than it back to work.
Anyone have any idea how to fix that problem? with the script I just cant type inside the inputs and the textarea.
thanks.

This is the script code:

```
     $('#masallery').ascensor({direction:"x",
         time: 800,
         overflow: 'hidden',
         windowsOn: 0
     });
```

This is the input code:

```
  $('input, textarea').attr("data-placeholdertext", function() {
    return this.value;
  });

  $('#form')
    .delegate('input, textarea', 'focus', function() {
        $(this).removeClass("formde").addClass("formde-click");  
      if (this.value === $(this).attr("data-placeholdertext")) {
        this.value = '';
      }
    })
    .delegate('input, textarea', 'blur', function() {
        $(this).removeClass("formde-click").addClass("formde");  
      if (this.value.length == 0) {
        this.value = $(this).attr("data-placeholdertext");
      }
    });
```

If I delete the first code, It is works.

When I enable the script, I can't type anything.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing I can't add more. I upgrade my work stage in my site with adding this script. than now I just noticed when Im using the script I cant type anything inside the inputs. I have no idea what the problem is with the script, that is what im asking here. thanks and sorry for missunderstand

Comment: Post your code, not a link to your site

Comment: I edited the main post with codes, I hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you try to validate fields on every keyup.
You should try to remove it from java.js

line 110

```
this.uname.on("keyup", this.isVaildName);
this.email.on("keyup", this.isVaildEmail);
this.cmsg.on("keyup",this.isVaildMsg);
```

Any way form validates on submit

Edit

Yep previos suggest was wrong, sorry was unmindful.

I think I have found now where there is a problem.

Ascensor bind itself to all keydown events. 
On line 146 it return "!1" if event comes from input/textarea.

!1 is false so it prevent default browser action (placing symbol to field).
If you change "!1" to "true" it should start work well.

Edit2:

Or you can disable key navigation feature.

```
$('#masallery').ascensor({direction:"x",
    time: 800,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    windowsOn: 0
    keyNavigation: false,
});
```

It should work too.

Comment: Nope it doesn't fix, and the keyup is realy important, and it works. The only problem was when I added the new script, I have no idea why it is happen. I would be happy if someone can find solution.